# My app is showing "This item is not compatible with your device"

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

i put my appliation in **Android Market**.It is showing **This item is not compatible with your device** for some devices like **Galaxy Y( Samsung GT-S5360)** and **HTC Explorer** and those devices have v2.3.5.

[image]

and my Manifest file is like below::

```
 ................
 ................
 android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Comment: Is your application using OpenGl, or any other kind of specific permissions ?

Comment: I am not using OpenGl in my app. and coming to permissions ..i have below....: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Probably these devices don't support OpenGl version in my opinion. I guess you are using OpenGl 2?

Comment: I am not using OpenGl

Comment: Oh sorry my bad...Do you have any of these devices? Can you run your app from eclipse to some of these devices?

Comment: yes i can run this app through eclipse on S5360.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your permissions.

See more about this here:

- [Manifest and supported devices showed in android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225580/manifest-and-supported-devices-showed-in-android-market)
- [Is there a way to install app that has send_sms permission on tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398194/is-there-a-way-to-install-app-that-has-send-sms-permission-on-tablet)
- [Why was our Application upgrade on Android Market not visible to all devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702049/why-was-our-application-upgrade-on-android-market-not-visible-to-all-devices)

It's difficult to say exactly which ones are causing the problems, I think it could be `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `CAMERA` but I have no access to these devices and no way to be sure.

In all cases the fix is not to remove the permissions but also use the `<uses-feature>` tags to ensure the market knows these are not *requirements* for your app.